# Accessing nested data in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have some JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
    "ValueDate": {
        "date": "2015-06-08 00:00:00",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
    },
    "JobBucket": "OPENBOOK",
    "Status": "Complete",
    "UpdateDate": {
        "date": "2015-06-09 03:10:11",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
    },
```

I have validated it and the formatting is correct.

I am trying to display this data in a tabular format from jQuery using a call like this:

```
output += "<td>" + json_obj[i].ValueDate.date + "</td>";
output += "<td>" + json_obj[i].JobBucket + "</td>";
output += "<td>" + json_obj[i].Status + "</td>";
output += "<td>" + json_obj[i].UpdateDate + "</td>";
```

I am able to access `date` from `ValueDate` but am unable to make it work for `UpdateDate`. Any ideas why?

For reference, `json_obj` is just my deserialised JSON:

```
var json_obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Comment: `$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));` isn't a sensible thing to do. You're turning an object into JSON, and then turning it back into the same object you already had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UpdateDate` is itself an object in the same format as `ValueDate`. As such you need to access the property you require from it to be displayed in the HTML string you're building, most likely `date`. Try this:

```
output += "<td>" + json_obj[i].UpdateDate.date + "</td>";
```

Also note that if you specify `dataType: 'json'` on your `$.ajax()` call, you don't need to manually parse the response using `$.parseJSON`/`JSON.stringify` as jQuery will do that for you.

Comment: I did try that but didn't work. The table just doesn't display when I do that. Weirdly it works for ValueDate.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console when that happened? There's nothing inherently wrong with the code in your question, so there may be an error elsewhere in your JS or server-side code.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the parse part. The error I see in the console is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of null

Ah...the first entry doesn't have date fields in JSON since it has null value so the code crashes there. Hmm I will have to add some sort of logic to avoid that from happening.